# PHP password_verify() doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

It gives incorrect password all the time. The password section in the DB is set to VARCHAR(256) so that is not the problem and if i try strlen($row['password']) it will return 60. Please help.

login.php

```
<html>

<form action="loginHandler.php" method="post">

Username: <input type="text" name="usernameLogin" value=""><br>

Password: <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" value=""><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitLogin" />


</html>
```

loginHandler.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitLogin']))
{
  $usernameLogin = ($_POST['usernameLogin']);
  $passwordLogin = ($_POST['passwordLogin']);
}

require("connectDB.php");

$dbname = "3year";
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM user_info WHERE username = '$usernameLogin'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1)
{
    if(password_verify($passwordLogin ,$row['password']))
        echo "Login successful!";
    else
        echo "Incorrect password!";
}
else
    echo "Username not valid!";


$conn->close();

?>
```

Inserting the password in the DB.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $mails = $_POST['email'];
}
else echo "Not set!";

echo $username;
require("connectDB.php");

$dbname = "3year";
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql = "INSERT INTO user_info (username, password, mails)
VALUES ('$username', '$hash', '$mails')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();


?>
```

Comment: Try this: `"SELECT username, password FROM user_info WHERE username = '{$usernameLogin}'"`. You could also dump the `$row['password']`.

Comment: Start by sanitizing your inputs and escape your variables you pass to mysqli_query.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier - prepared statements would be a better approach

Comment: @MarkBaker I totally agree with you, prepared statement is the best, but passing raw inputs is like going to war with a bikini. At least get dress for the job :P

Comment: Guys, 1st want to figure this out and then will go and find ways to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: But password shouldn't be escaped/filtered/modified as it isn't being used in SQL

Comment: Have you checked the length of the password column in the database? Was the password generated using password_hash()?

Comment: VARCHAR(256) and yes used that function, now included the code how I am storing the password.